# TFS build java software using ant

Tags: java, tfs, ant

I am trying to build java software in tfs using ANT. I see this error

```
No agent found in pool XYZ pool which satisfies the specified demands:
     ant
     Agent.Version -gtVersion 1.91.0
```

And this is the screenshot of agent pool[image]

In the system capabilities of the agent I see agent version as 2.131.0.

I am not understanding what does the error tell. Also I don't get what does Agent.version mean?

Below is the tfs build definition, I am not sure I have configured the tfs ANT correctly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you install ant on the build servers? Did you restart the build agent software after installing ant?

Comment: Thanks @DanielMann that helped

Answer (score 0):

> No agent found in pool XYZ pool which satisfies the specified demands:
>        ant
>        Agent.Version -gtVersion 1.91.0

The error means you have an environment issue , such as ant not installed or couldn't captured by TFS build agent.

**The build agent will not detect the environment changes after you installed it.** It will only detect during the installation.

Since you are using vNext build agent, first double check some capabilities added in *Settings- Agent Queues- Agent Pool - Agent- Capabilities*.

Then you need to restart corresponding VSO agent service. After this trigger the build again.